# Set content-length limit on response in mod_proxy

Tags: http, proxy, mod-proxy, content-length, proxy-server

I want to set a limit in my proxy server that if the response content-length is less than a threshold value only then the response is returned.

How can I do it in my proxy server?
I searched for mod_proxy in http server but no luck.

Thanks in advance.